# Send a log to Crashlytics without an app crash

Tags: ios, crashlytics

How can I get Crashlytics to receive a log without my app crashing?
I have the following code:

```
if(!context.managedObjectContext save:&error) {
    CLS_LOG(@"%@",error.description)
}
```

When an error occurs, I want the Crashlytics server to receive the error but the app should continue running.

I do not need the log right away. I would be happy to get the log on the next restart. I just do not want to have to trigger a crash in my app to  receive the log.

Is this possible?

Comment: You don't. This is not what it's intended it. Try flurry, they allow you to send 'check point' messages.

Comment: That would mean I would need to use both flurry and Crashlytics. I do think I have a valid use case. Sometimes the error is serious but doesn't warrant a crash so it would be nice to get the error with crashlytics. but of course you do have a point

Comment: I use both. Bit of a pain but it's better to use tools are they're intended. At least in my opinion. Rather than 'hacking' them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crashlytics iOS - log caught exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118742/crashlytics-ios-log-caught-exception)

Comment: https://docs.fabric.io/ios/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html

Answer (score 60):

With the new update from crashlytics you can now use:

```
[[FIRCrashlytics crashlytics] recordError:error];
```

And in Swift:

```
Crashlytics.crashlytics().record(error: error)
```

You can check the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=ios#log-excepts).

Comment: This should be the answer.

Comment: Like crashes, these recorded errors are only sent on the next app launch, which is unfortunate if the user never force quits the app.

Comment: Where can you watch those event in the fabric console ?

Comment: Hi @SaeedNeamati, this is Objective-c and it refers to the Crashlytics Framework in iOS

Answer (score 14):

Kinda old question, but now you can use `Answers` which is part of the `Fabric` suit (`Crashlytics` is part of `Fabric` as well):

[image]

[Fabric](https://fabric.io/) can be found here. And further documentation [here](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/index.html).

Comment: This answer is outdated. Tiago Almeida answer is the way to go.

Comment: @Lupi not it's not: https://docs.fabric.io/ios/answers/answers-events.html#custom-event. It's a valid solution.

Comment: Answers is more related to Marketing and Big Data, definitely not for error tracking.

Comment: @Lupi: There is a cost to the recordError due to stack unwinding not being optional. Additionally as others have noted, the recordError is only sent on next app launch. In cases such as counting in near real-time number of certain error occurrences, Answers could be a viable & preferred solution as Fabric's documentation outlines under Performance Considerations: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/logged-errors.html#performance-considerations

Answer (score 8):

I tried the below lines and it works like charm. In try-catch block use the below lines in your catch block

```
@try {
// line of code here
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
NSUncaughtExceptionHandler *handler = NSGetUncaughtExceptionHandler();
handler(exception);
}
```

as explained at http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/222764-can-i-use-a-custom-exception-handler

[UPDATE]

Now in fabric's crashlytics we can use simple function `[Crashlytics recordCustomExceptionName:reason:frameArray:]` for sending handled exceptions

```
@try {
// line of code here
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSArray *stack = [exception callStackReturnAddresses];
    [[Crashlytics sharedInstance] recordCustomExceptionName: exception.name
                                                 reason: exception.reason
                                             frameArray: stack];
}
```

as explained at
https://twittercommunity.com/t/crashlytics-ios-how-to-send-non-fatal-exceptions-without-app-crash/34592/32

Comment: Swift doens't support exceptions or try/catch for NSExceptions. You can write a class in Objective-C which takes an NSString parameter for the exception name and call it from swift?

Comment: You can call NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler from swift

Answer (score 4):

For me the method `.recordError()` didn't helped, because it don't log the user information. Or i just didn't found where to watch it. Using `recordCustomExceptionName` fit to me. There is an example of implementation of the both ways:

```
func logMessage(_ message: String) {
    let userInfo = ["message" : message]
    let error = NSError(domain: "AppErrorDomain", code: 1, userInfo: userInfo)
    Crashlytics.sharedInstance().recordCustomExceptionName("API Error", reason: message, frameArray: [])
    Crashlytics.sharedInstance().recordError(error, withAdditionalUserInfo: userInfo)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5, Crashlytics SDK 4.0.0-beta.6:

```
let exceptionModel = ExceptionModel(name: "exception title", reason: "details")
Crashlytics.crashlytics().record(exceptionModel: exceptionModel)
```

...similar for NSError, with whatever you want to see in the Crashlytics dashboard.

```
let error = NSError(domain: "error title", code: 0, userInfo: ["message":"some details"])
Crashlytics.crashlytics().record(error: error)
```

Comment: I added the above to the project and tested it. However, it was not displayed in the Crashlytics dashboard. Even though I repeatedly re-launched the app, it is not visible. What should I check?
(The existing method of causing a crash is working well.)

Comment: @KimJitae it might be you're not seeing it in the dashboard because the default settings there are set to `Event type = "Crashes"` above the "Crash-free statistics" box.  Clear that setting, and you should see it down below as a "Non-fatal".

Answer (score 1):

**iOS log non-fatal exception**

[official doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=ios#log-excepts)

```
Crashlytics.crashlytics().record(error: error)
```

Also please take a look at the testing phase. Actually Firebase [recommends](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=ios):

- don't use debug mode
- logged error is sent on the **next app launch**
- you can use `-FIRDebugEnabled` in a schema arguments[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59215808/4770877) and find `Completed report submission` in logs to be sure that it is sent
- wait more then 5 minutes(~1 hour in my case)
- I could find log in dashboard only from a real device(not simulator)
- If you used `-FIRDebugEnabled` you can still see logs after disabling or removing this argument. To fix it use `-FIRDebugDisabled` argument

Comment: Thanks a lot! This saved me so much time. I was debugging it for the 2 days trying to find out why doesn't it send reports. All I needed to do is relaunch app...

Answer (score -3):

In reference from Crashlytics documents.

```
try {
  myMethodThatThrows();
} catch (Exception e) {
  Crashlytics.logException(e);
  // handle your exception here!
}
```

https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/caught-exceptions.html?caught%20exceptions#caught-exceptions

Comment: Your method from the android documentation does not exist on ios

Answer (score -4):

As far as I know, if you dont protect your code correctly, your application will crash anyway. Crashlylytics, take this crashes and show them to you in a "readable" mode in the web application they have designed. If there is no crash, crashlytics will take anything. You can grab an exception in your code :

```
@try{
....
}
@catch(NSException ex){...}
```

in the critical parts, but you should always do that if you are afraid your application is going to crash or you find a potential error which can allow your application have a bad behavior and acting up. You can always force in your exception to send or track this error.

Hope it helps

Comment: This doesn't even remotely address the OP's question.

Comment: Maybe if you read when it was posted and how Crashlytics and the different platforms have evolved, it would have sense. I think is better to see the dates before to vote negative to someone. Thanks

Comment: No, it wouldn't have. OP asked how to get a report for non-fatal errors from Crashlytics, which wasn't an option at the time. Your answer was how to prevent the app from crashing in the first place. Totally unrelated.

Answer (score -4):

Crashlytics is a crash tracking service, if you need to track custom messages choose other analytics service.

Answer (score -4):

The trick is to use the following :

http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/202805-logging-caught-exceptions

Just use this :

```
Crashlytics.logException(new Exception("my custom log for crashLytics !!!"));
```

I use this and I get my non-fatal crash in about 5 minutes !

Comment: It seems like this feature is Android only.