# Is there any solution for send non fatal crash from ios with crashlytics?

Tags: ios, exception, logging, crashlytics

I try to find any solution to send non fatal exception on iOS with crashlytics service. Is that possible? How to achieve this?

Comment: There's no such thing as a non-fatal crash. But if you catch a catchable exception in a try-catch block, you can do whatever you want with the caught NSException instance.

Comment: @rmaddy O thank you. but could you provide any code examples?

Comment: Find some Objective-C tutorials that cover exception handling using `@try/@catch`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crashlytics iOS - log caught exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118742/crashlytics-ios-log-caught-exception)

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/logged-errors.html

> Using the API You can record an NSError using this API:
>
> `[CrashlyticsKit recordError:error];`
>
> `Crashlytics.sharedInstance().recordError(error)`

Answer (score 1):

Crashlytics introduced this functionality in Jan 2016 and published this blog post:
https://www.crashlytics.com/blog/introducing-the-ability-to-log-nserrors

Implementation Details:

```
https://docs.fabric.io/ios/crashlytics/logged-errors.html
```

Very similar to what Crashlytics provides for Android where you have to use try/catch:
http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/202805-logging-caught-exceptions

Crashlytics also [talks](https://www.crashlytics.com/blog/introducing-the-ability-to-log-nserrors) about why they do not support NSException, but NSError instead.

Answering an old question in case someone stumbles upon it as I did! :)